# Regex - Match a single instance/occurrence of a character per line

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds, nsregularexpression

I really am not getting how I can match just a single instance of both a whitespace or a dash. I am able to get some results but still unable to get the desired one. I have actually tried different configurations from regexr.com and what not but still cant get it to work.[regex padawan here]

```
Shell: Powershell
Data : "test--asd :45; wth---notcool:  69"

Index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
Value   t   e   s   t   -   -   a   s   d       :   4   5   ;       w   t   h   -   -   -   n   o   t   c   o   o   l   :           6   9
```

Test 1 regex = `'([\s\-])\1?'`

Test 2 regex = `'([\s\-]){1}'`

```
Testing 1         Testing 2       Desired to be REMOVED 
Index   Value     Index Value     Index Value
-----   -----     ----- -----     ----- -----
4       --        4     -         5     -
9                 5     -         9 
14                9               14    
18      --        14              19    -
20      -         18    -         20    -
29                19    -         30        
                  20    -       
                  29            
                  30
```

I think im missing something really basic here or fundamental, but my main goal with this is that I want to use regex to basically reduce the spaces and dashes to a single instance each so that the string isn't messy.

```
******* EDIT (Added explanation) *******
```

Basically, what I need to do is to get rid of the white-spaces and to transform the redundant dashes to a single dash. This is why I thought I could create a regex to select(get the index) the white-spaces and the extra dashes(starting from the 2nd consecutive dash) and replace them as nothing(''). Sorry for the confusion, having a difficulty in stating the issue and the correct approach.

So the main goal is reflected below, I jsut need to get rid of the ones in yellow:

[image: Final desired output]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen!  its labeled as `"Desired Output"`

Comment: So you just want to replace any instance of 2 or more - with one -? And the same for spaces?

Comment: was aout for lunch folks sorry!What TessellatingHeckler said was actually close buddy. I just need to change the repeating Hyphens(dash) to be a single dash, and remove the spaces so I thought I could just look for a single dash with a nearby dash and the white space(which i see isn't the correct logic). @EBGreen

Comment: "*having a difficulty in stating the issue*" -  if only you had a small, precise language for describing text patterns to help you  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

- spaces replaced with nothing
- multiple dashes reduced to a single dash

That means any regex which matches (space or dash) is going to have to have a replacement value which varies, based on whether it matches a space or a dash. Possible, but annoying.

Instead, I would rephrase it to make the replacement value the same for both cases - empty string - and that makes things which should be replaced:

- One or more dashes *following a dash* get replaced with nothing, the leading dash stays
- space

Which would be:

```
PS C:\> "test--asd :45; wth---notcool:  69" -replace '(?<=-)-+|\s'
test-asd:45;wth-notcool:69
```

That is, `(?<=-)` for a lookbehind matching a dash which will stay in the string, `-+` for one or more dashes after it (these will be replaced with nothing). `|` or. `\s` a whitespace character.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion , but this is really close! i've added more information for clarity. I know I can just chain another `Replace` method to the result to change the space to nothing but I wanted to explore regex if its capable of replacing multiple characters at the same time like my desired output. @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: THANKS A LOT MAN!! @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: hey mannn would it be okay if I let you read my most updated question? Sorry to bother you. @TessellatingHeckler